# Pentaho freeform component

Tags: pentaho

I am using CDE to create a Pentaho Dashboard. But I need to present the data in many ways where no component is useful. So I would like to use the Free Form Component to paint the data myself.

How do I access my data from the Free Form Component? For example, I'd like to loop the resultset, and for each row, write the data in some custom way.

But I don't know how to access the data from the query I defined in the Datasource. I tried:

```
function (dataset) {

for (var i=0; i < dataset.resultset.length; i++) {
```

Like I saw in some post-fetch example, but it didn't work.

I am finding almost 0 info on how to code anything CDE. Is there no API anywhere?
Thanks for any help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

Either post-fetch or post execution should do. When you say it didn't work, what happened ? 
Errors in the javascript console ? Are you sure the data is getting to the component ?

Lots of resources for CDE can be found in the pentaho forums at http://forums.pentaho.com/forumdisplay.php?80-Community-Tools-CTools.

Comment: When I try to preview it says: Error in component

Just for testing if I can access the data i did this: in Post-Fetch:
`function f(dataset) {
    for (var i=0; i < dataset.resultset.length; i++) 
    {
         $("#" + this.htmlObject).text("test: " + i);
    }
}`

Comment: _Are you sure the data is getting to the component ?_  That's exactly my problem. In the Datasource property I put my working query. But then I don't know how to access that data from the post-fetch script (or similar)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the freeform component doesn't run the query unless you explicitly tell it to.

One way around it, without having to code the doQuery method of the freeform component, is using a query component that fetches the data and in the postFetch fireChanges a parameter that the freeform component listens to.

Then you can refer to the data on the queryComponent by looking into `render_<queryComponentName>.queryState.lastResults()`.